# Customize NSOutlineView row editing

Tags: nstableview, nsoutlineview

I' ve a `NSOutlineView` configured as SourceList. When I double click on a row this become editable and I want to modify the apparence of that TextField (or NSTextView?). Anyone know how to do that? thanks!